# Why is the object 'state' not found in this DataCamp exercise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having an issue with a DataCamp exercise where I am getting an error message that my variable 'state' is not found. My code is identical to the solution code, unless I am missing something, but for some reason when I copy-paste the solution code state *is* found and when I type my own it's not.

Does anyone see what I am missing or know why the object isn't found in my own code?

```
counties_selected %>%
  # Add population_walk containing the total number of people who walk to work 
    mutate(population_walk <- walk * population) 

  # Count weighted by the new column

  counties_selected %>% 
  group_by(state) %>%
  count(population_walk, sort=TRUE)
```

And the error message in the console:

```
>   count(state, wt = population_walk, sort = TRUE)
Error: object 'state' not found
> 
>   #count(counties_selected, population_walk, wt = state, sort = TRUE)
```

Comment: `mutate(population_walk <- walk * population)` change the `<-` to `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the code. 1) Inside the tidyverse functions, the assignment is usually carried out with `=` and in certain cases while evaluating, use `:=`, i.e. the `<-`is not used for assignment, 2).  The object is not updated.  So, if we don't assign the output of `mutate` to the same object, it would not be updated

```
library(dplyr)
counties_selected <- counties_selected %>%  
             mutate(population_walk  = walk * population)
```

Now, the second part of the code would work